# Android-Wear in app purchasing null pointer

Tags: android, wear-os

In app purchasing works on my "mobile" module however it does not work on my "wear" module of the same project. I use the exact same code with the "wear" module that I do with the "mobile" module, however on the "wear" module I get a null pointer exception.

```
IabHelper mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
    {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                    result);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea how to fix or if Android-Wear even supports in app purchasing?

Relevant stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.util.IabHelper.startSetup(IabHelper.java:267)
```

Comment: stack trace? what line is the NPE occurring on? if i were to guess, in-app purchases are not supported.

Comment: Indicate where line 267 is in your snippet.

Comment: On a related note, check out http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/update-on-android-wear-paid-apps.html

Comment: @PeterFriese this did not solve my problem with in app purchasing. So the question remains: DOES ANDROID WEAR SUPPORT IN APP PURCHASING?

Comment: @cybersam the problem is with this line: mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

Comment: There is not internet connectivity on Wear devices at this time, so you have to handle that with your handheld connectivity and communicate between your devices.